# In Scrapy extract_first() doesnt return complete text if the string length is very large

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am scraping a site using Scrapy that returns json type file in string format.

When i use the below selector i get complete data as expected inside a list.

```
response.xpath('//p/text()').extract()
```

The data inside this list is a json like string which i need to convert into a dictionary for which i am using `json.loads()`

But the problem occurs when i use the below selector for getting the json like string present inside the list.

```
response.xpath('//p/text()').extract_first()
```

This gives partial truncated string as and output and hence `json.loads()` gives and error of Unterminated string.

Note: I tried similar selectors like `.extract()[0], getall()[0]` etc. all run into same problem.
Also while printing it prints truncated partial string.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? URL of website you are scraping at least. It might or might not be a bug in the parsel library.

Comment: Does the response contain a separate blob of Javascript in each `<p>`? Would it be possible to paste or link an example?

Comment: @Sitanshu.K That URL returns a JSON response already. Why are you extracting it with an XPath?

Comment: "https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/AnnGetData/w?strCat=-1&strPrevDate=20190201&strScrip=&strSearch=P&strToDate=20190201&strType=C"
This is the url i am scraping.@Tomáš Linhart

Comment: i want to filter the data received through it.
i am using pipelines for that.

Comment: can you suggest some other approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an XPath extractor like that is likely to mess up the data. Since the URL returns JSON in the first place, you can just load that whole response into a JSON object:

```
import json
json_data = json.loads(response.text)

# Items are available in json_data['Table']
```

Here's what the browser sees inside that:
[image: JSON Fields]